# 0% of the site has been indexed in drupal how to solve this isse?

Tags: drupal-7

Your search yielded no results in Drupal 7.12. I have index 0%. In my local it is working but on the staging server it is not working.Check if your spelling is correct. Remove quotes around phrases to search for each word individually. bike shed will often show more results than "bike shed". Consider loosening your query with OR. bike OR shed will often show more results than bike shed.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution just install spambot module and configure then run the cron manually.

Answer (score 0):

Should just need to run the cron, /admin/config/system/cron, either manually or set the "Run cron every" setting. Every time the cron runs it indexes a certain amount of the site.